# Deployment software for node.js & mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, deployment, jenkins, web-deployment

I have my production and development servers (developed in node.js) on AWS as different instant, and connect to different mongoDB server.    The code is in github repo.

So, I want to find out what is the easiest way to do deployment after changes are confirmed at Dev server.

What I would like to do is once I confirmed Dev is good, then I just go to a deployment panel or page that I can press a button and then the Prod will get the latest code from git and get the latest copy of data from dev db, and copy to prod mongoDB.  All data are static, no user data.

I have used Jenkins but never installed it.  and I feel that Jenkins will be too big for that simple task. (or not?)

Is there an easier solutions? or it is better for me to just spend my time installing Jenkins?

Oh. I'm on Ubuntu. Is that a problem installing Jenkins onto it?

Comment: Why not something like Grunt? It's great at what it does, and you would basically just change a command line arg.

Comment: does Grunt have a web interface?

Comment: Natively, no. But there may exist some 3rd-party GUI for Grunt.

Answer (score 1):

We use [CircleCi](https://circleci.com) for our continuous integration.  Circle makes it easy to do deployment workflows based on the branch that is pushed.  Plug for CircleCi.

We had a Jenkins server, please just quit using it because it was a hassle compared to a hosted service.

We do a similar process for one of our tool sets.  We use the `master` branch for development, and the release branch for production.  The exception is a successful test run builds our `release` branch, not a human clicking a button.  Do something like the following:

1. Develop your code in a `master` branch
2. Changes to your `master` branch are pushed to your development machines
3. You create a button that executes an action to merge into the release branch, and push back to origin:

   `git fetch origin/release && git rebase origin/master && git checkout release && git merge master && git push origin release`

If someone makes the release branch unmergeable from master, your auto-merge button, which is good.  It will require some manual interaction then.